# How to reorder tensor based on indexes tensor from the same size

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Say I have `tensor` `A`, and indexes `Tensor`: `A = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, `indexes = [1, 0, 3, 2]`

I want to create a new `Tensor` from these two with the following result : `[2, 1, 4, 3]`
Each element of the result is element from `A` and the order is defined by the indexes `Tensor`.
Is there a way to do it with PyTorch `tensor` ops without loops?

My goal is to do it for 2D `Tensor`, but I don't think there is a way to do it without loops, so I thought to project it to 1D, do the work and project it back to the 2D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [scatter](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_):

```py
A = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
indices = torch.tensor([1, 0, 3, 2])
result = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 0])
print(result.scatter_(0, indices, A))
```

Answer (score 0):

In 1D you can simply perform `A[indexes]`.

In 2D it is still doable in this way:

```py
A = torch.arange(5, 10).repeat(3, 1)  # shape: (3, 5)
indexes = torch.stack([torch.randperm(5) for _ in range(3)])  # shape (3, 5)

A_sort = A[torch.arange(3).unsqueeze(1), indexes]
print(A_sort)
```

Comment: Hi. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.
Regarding the 2D solution i'm getting an error, maybe you meant:
A_sort = A[range(5)[0], indexes]?

Comment: There was an error, now it should work.